# If $a$ is a positive integer of the type $3n+2$,then pove that at-least one prime divisor of $a$ is of the form $3n+2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $a$ is a positive integer of the type $3n+2$,then pove that at-least one prime divisor of $a$ is of the form $3n+2$

My try:If $3n+2$ is prime then we are done since $3n+2$ is of the form $3n+2$. What do we do in the case it isn't prime?

Comment: Hint: What happens if you multiple two primes which are equivalent to $1\pmod 3$?

Comment: Trivial question: if every prime divisor of $3n+2$ were of the form $3k+1$ then $3n+2$ would be of the same form, contradiction. It follows that every number of the form $3n+2$ has to have a prime divisor of such a form.